# HighCharts with CodeIgniter results nothing for MySQL fetched data

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter, highcharts

I wanted to display data from database table in a bar chart. I used HighCharts library. The chart obviously loaded with default template data. But then I made some changes so that it can represent data from database. Although I think the flow of logic is correct, it doesn't show anything at all now. FYI: My knowledge on JSON and AJAX are nit very big.

**View:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

Highcharts.setOptions({
colors: ['#e74c3c']
});  

$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Daily Income'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2013-08-10', '2013-08-11', '2013-08-12']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Daily Income From Banquet Reservations For Last 30 Days'
        }
    },
    series: <?php echo $json; // echo encoded data ?>
    }],
});
});

});

</script>
```

...

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
    function bqt_daily_income() {
    $this->load->model('reports_model');
    $this->load->model('json_model'); // load model

    $report['query'] = $this->reports_model->bqt_daily_income();
    $table['income'] = $this->json_model->bqt_daily_income(); // fetch data from mysql database 
    $json['table'] = json_encode($table); // encode to json
    $data = array_merge($report, $json); // merge with other arrays as i also have a html table with raw data from database

    $role = $this->session->userdata('role');
    if ($role === 'admin') { $this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', $data); } // load view with data array (merged)
    else if ($role === 'manager') { $this->load->view('error'); }
    else if ($role === 'user') { $this->load->view('error'); }
    else { $this->load->view('login');}
}
```

**Model:** (json_model)

```
function bqt_daily_income($json_data = array()) {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE(time_stamp) AS day,  SUM(paid) AS income FROM payments WHERE type = 'Banquet Reservation' GROUP BY day ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 30");
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
     foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
     $json_data[$row['day']] = $row['income'];
     }
  }
  return $json_data;
```

}

Comment: I advice to use json_encode() in return.

Comment: `HighCharts`, `CodeIgniter`, `MySQL`. Ask a specific question, then expect to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your controller and I think you will be good to go. See the **comments** for the changes made.
**EDITED**

```
function bqt_daily_income() {
    $this->load->model('reports_model');
    $this->load->model('json_model'); // load model

    $report['query'] = $this->reports_model->bqt_daily_income();
    $table['income'] = $this->json_model->bqt_daily_income(); // fetch data from mysql database 
    $data['json']   = json_encode($table['income']); // CHANGES HERE FOR THE JS
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['json']); echo "</pre>";die;  //TO SEE IF THE JSON IS RETURNING CORRECTLY FROM THE MODEL OR NOT
    $data['merged'] = array_merge($report, $json); // NOW IN VIEW USE $merged FOR THE MERGED ARRAY
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['json']); echo "</pre>";die;  //TO SEE IF THE MERGED IS OKAY OR NOT
    $role = $this->session->userdata('role');
    if ($role === 'admin') { $this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', $data); } // load view with data array (merged)
    else if ($role === 'manager') { $this->load->view('error'); }
    else if ($role === 'user') { $this->load->view('error'); }
    else { $this->load->view('login');}
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but it resulted errors. Undefined variable and argument #1 is not an array errors. I also tried passing only the $json variable to see whether array_merge cause this. But apparently it's not.

Comment: Do you need the merged array as `json` or just what you are returning?  Where are you getting the above error though?

Comment: Actually, merge is not relevant to HighChart chart I wanted. I had to merge as arrays as I wanted to populate a chart as well as a HTML table in the same view. It's OK if I can print the chart at least. Proavably using $json['table'] = json_encode($table);